# Fixing load static Django Templates

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I've been searching for an answer to this and I feel like I'm doing everything right and have taken on suggestions in multiple posts but this is still stumping me. I'm trying to load static in my django template but for some reason I keep getting and unresolved template error and it won't load in my browser.

project/settings.py

```py
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_FILES_FIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
```

I've set up the static root.
Then in my base.html I've got:

```html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="{% static "favicon/favicon.png" %}">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>
<body>

{% include "navbar.html" %}

<img src="{% static "favicon/favicon.png" %}" alt="img"/>

<main class="container mx-auto p-8">
    {% block main %}{% endblock %}
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

I feel like I'm missing something obvious because that directory should exist but the django template isn't finding it! I've tried using {% load staticfiles %} instead but that errors saying it can't find staticfiles. Any help would be appreciated!

Edit:
I'm using django 4.0.6 if that makes a difference!

Edit:
Image of folder structure:

[image: folder structure]

Edit:
Logs that appear when I load the page:

```bash
[27/Jul/2022 19:01:58] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 15090
[27/Jul/2022 19:01:58] "GET /static/logo.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1783
[27/Jul/2022 19:01:59] "GET /static/favicon/favicon.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1816
```

EDIT SOLVED:
I'm not entirely sure why this solved it but I just removed the STATIC_ROOT setting. Now all my images and static files are loading correctly.

Thanks,
Mitchell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue by removing the STATIC_ROOT setting.

I can't explain why this works but I'll take it.

Answer (score 0):

First off,

STATIC_FILES_FIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]

Should be

STATICFILES_**D**IRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]

Aside from that - check in settings if DEBUG is set to True or False. If False, make sure you have run `python manage.py collectstatic` and that it has put your files into your STATIC_ROOT folder - which should be BASE_DIR/static

If that doesn't help, look at the HTML in your browser and see what img src is being generated there, and also at your BASE_DIR value to make sure you're starting at the right level.

If you are running in production mode (DEBUG = False) locally, you may wish to use the `python manage.py runserver --insecure` argument to get static files to load without an actual webserver. See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#runserver) for more

Comment: Ahh yep, good spot. Unfortunately that hasn't helped. The path in my browser looks correct. I've run collect static and it places my admin and django toolbar in the same folder I'm placing the favicon. Interestingly I'm also deploying to a test production server using gunicorn and nginx there and the images are displayed correctly...

Comment: so by the looks of it, your favicon img src should be /static/favicon/favicon.png and your static folder should be /static/favicon/favicon.png.  There's no additional appname in your folder, eg static/appname/favicon/favicon.png?

Comment: Nope my folder structure looks correct. I've added a picture of what I'm seeing on my original post. That's the img src directory I'm seeing in the browser as well.

Comment: What is your BASE_DIR set to?

Comment: I haven't changed this so it's set to what Django defaults to:

```BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent```

Comment: That would put your settings.py at the same level as the wsgi.py file pictured. Sometimes, especially if there are multiple settings files for prod and dev, people create a settings subfolder and forget to update.

Comment: The project I'm working on is completely separate from my production environment. What I'm working with is close to a default django startproject. The wsgi is in the same folder as the settings.py. I haven't created any separate settings file for this project

Comment: Added a suggestion for running in production mode locally to answer.

Comment: This hasn't worked unfortunately

Comment: Can you provide the full error?

Comment: I've added what I see when I load the page to my question.

Comment: I somehow solved this issue